# Ayuda PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

Reconfiguro mi pregunta ya que solucione el primer problema

**Por aqui tenemos lo que recibimos por POST Y AJAX del formulario y lo metemos en la SQL**

```
<?php
 include "../conexion/conexion.php";

 mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");
 $results = 'SELECT * FROM Usuarios';
 $rec = mysqli_query($mysqli, $results);

 if ($rec === false) {
 die('ERROR SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($mysqli)));
 }
 while ($results = mysqli_fetch_object($rec)) {

if(mb_strtolower($results->Username) == mb_strtolower($_POST['email'])) 
 {

die('<div class=\'form\'> 
     <div class="alert alert-danger" style="font-size: 14px;"> 
      <strong>¡Error!</strong> Este usuario ya esta en uso.</div>         
    </div>');
 }

 }

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']);
$telefono = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['telefono']);
$movil = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['movil']);
$nif = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['nif']);
$direccion = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['direccion']);
$postal = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['postal']);
$poblacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['poblacion']);
$provincia = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['provincia']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['pass']);
$sexo = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['sexo']);

$fecha = date('y,m,d');

$results = "
INSERT INTO Usuarios (
    Fecha,
    Sexo,
    Nombre,
    Password,
    Username,
    Direccion,
    Postal,
    Poblacion,
    Provincia,
    Telefono,
    Movil,
    Dni,
    intestado
) VALUES (
    '$fecha',
    '$sexo',
    '$name',
    '$pass',
    '$email',
    '$direccion',
    '$postal',
    '$poblacion',
    '$provincia',
    '$telefono',
    '$movil',
    '$nif',
    '1'
   )
  ";
 if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $results) === false) {
/* Aquí olvidaste poner como primer parámetro la conexión mysqli */
die('Error SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($mysqli)));
}
```

**Luego ya tenemos el PHPMailer**

```
include "../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php";
include "../PHPMailer/class.smtp.php";

$email_user = "hola@depildiodo.com";
$email_password = "churrero";
$the_subject = "Bienvenid@ $name";
$address_to = "info@artdesigns.es";
$from_name = "Depildiodo";
$body = file_get_contents("http://webnueva.depildiodo.com/plantillaEmail/template.html");
$phpmailer = new PHPMailer();

$phpmailer->Username = $email_user;
$phpmailer->Password = $email_password; 
$phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 1;
$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$phpmailer->Host = "mail.depildiodo.com"; // GMail
$phpmailer->Port = 465;
$phpmailer->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpmailer->setFrom($phpmailer->Username,$from_name);
$phpmailer->AddAddress($address_to); // recipients email
$phpmailer->Subject = $the_subject; 
$phpmailer->Body = $body;
//$phpmailer->Body .="<h1 style='color:#3498db;'>Hola $name!</h1>";
//$phpmailer->Body .= "<p>Mensaje personalizado</p>";
//$phpmailer->Body .= "<p>Fecha y Hora: ".date("d-m-Y h:i:s")."</p>";
$phpmailer->IsHTML(true);
$phpmailer->Send();
```

Y luego la plantilla del mail; /plantillaEmail/template.html (Esto esta en otro archivo)

Y lo que necesito es que la información que traigo por POST meterla en esa plantilla.

Comment: Estoy utilizando esto para mandar la plantilla pero no se como cargar los datos de post:
$body = file_get_contents("http://direccionplantilla.html");
$phpmailer->Body = $body;

Comment: ¿Imprimir qué datos?

Comment: Pues antes del codigo que ves, recibo por post unos datos de un formulario por metodo post, como nombre, email, etc...

Comment: Recibes unos datos por `POST` ¿y luego?  ... ¿No crees que deberías explicarte mejor en la pregunta? No estamos ante tu dispositivo ni en tu mente  como para saber como tú lo que intentas hacer. Si no te explicas bien es más difícil poder ayudarte.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, no estoy en la oficina ahora. Veras no se si sirvira, hay un formulario de registro de usuario, el usuario lo rellena, por ajax se envia a otro documento donde lo recibimos por post y lo insertanos en la sql, la idea es enviar un mail de bienvenida con los datos del usuario, enviar el mail lo hago sin problema del modo que explico arriba, pero e creado una plantilla en html para poder llenarla de esos datos y enviarla por mail, no se si queda claro asi!?? Si no tendre que amoliar la pregunta mañana en la oficina

Comment: Sería cuestión de incluir el archivo donde llenas los datos (plantilla) y agregarlos al `body` de tu mensaje de email. Supongamos que el contenido de la plantilla se guarda en una variable PHP llamada `$html`, incluyes tu archivo con `include` y luego haces esto: `$phpmailer->Body .=$html;` y la plantilla se agregará al cuerpo del mensaje.

Comment: Y como añado los post al archivo de la plantilla si esta en ltro archivo distinto al quebrecibimos por ajax?

Comment: ¿Por qué en un archivo distinto?  Lo correcto sería hacer todo eso desde el archivo que recibe los datos vía Ajax. Ese debe ser el archivo que procese todos los datos recibidos desde el cliente. Le puedes delegar a él también el envío del email, ¿para qué quieres meter un tercer archivo, qué sentido tendría? A lo sumo, si tienes una clase que maneje los envíos de email, en ese mismo archivo que procesará la petición Ajax puedes crear una instancia de esa clase. Creo que te estás haciendo un lío simplemente porque no tienes bien planteada la organización de tus archivos.

Comment: Perdona tube que salir. Cuando estes por aquí, te importaria que lo miraramos bien? @A.Cedano gracias

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que tanto el código de más arriba como el código que procesa los datos que vienen de Ajax puede estar en un solo archivo. Si quieres tener una plantilla en un archivo separado lo puedes hacer, pero basta con hacer un `include` de tu archivo de plantilla siempre en el mismo archivo PHP que maneja la petición Ajax.

Comment: Vamos hacer una cosa, te lo voy a poner todo para que entiendas 100% bien como esta hecho, si te parece bien

Comment: Adelante, puedes editar la pregunta y ponerlo, pero explicando cada cosa. No sueltes una biblioteca de código para que uno tenga que analizarla adivinando  lo que hace cada cosa.

Comment: Creo que lo he explicado bien, al final son 3 partes, lo que recibo por AJAX, meterlo en la SQL y después PHPMailer

Comment: Es que realmente estás enfocando un procedimiento inverso. Tú tienes una plantilla HTML y quieres poner en ella contenido PHP. Realmente, la forma más fácil de hacer esto sería la siguiente: 1. Creas tu plantilla en un archivo con extensión `.php`, **no en un archivo con extensión `.html`. Ese archivo usará variables para los datos que quieres, por ejemplo `$nombre, $apellido`, etc...; 2. En el archivo PHP en que recibes la petición Ajax (1ra parte del código de tu pregunta) haces todo el manejo y creas las variables que requieras;  3. Una vez creadas las variables, incluyes la plantilla ...

Comment: Siendo asi como dices, no imprimira en pantalla la plantilla ademas de enviarla por mail?? te lo comento porque ya me paso

Comment: ... de ese modo, la plantilla tomará el valor de las variables previamente creadas. De ahí mi recomendación en el punto 1 de crear el archivo de la plantilla con extensión `.php`, porque de ese modo las variables creadas con los datos del POST se presentarán en la plantilla sin problemas. Mientras que presentar código PHP en un archivo con extensión HTML es mucho más complicado y además inseguro...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83987/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-miguel).